# Find the initial position equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, physics

I've been solving initial value problems but this one has me stumped.

So far what I have is that the position when r(0) is $(8,6,5)$
My next given is when $v(0)=8$
Next, the particle moves in a straight line to $(9,8,4)$
I've calculated that the direction vector between $P1$ and $P2$ is the same as the acceleration vector which is my next given.
Acceleration is constant $a(t)=i+2j-k$

My thought process has led me so far to
1) Integrate the acceleration vector:
$$P_0(8,6,5), P_1(9,8,4)$$
$$P_1P_2=a(t)$$
$$a(t)=i+2j-k$$
$$\int{a(t)dt}=v(t)=(t+C_1)i+(2t+C_2)j-(t+C_3)k$$
$$|a(t)|=\sqrt6$$
$$|v(0)|=8$$
$$v(0)=((0)+C_1))i+(2(0)+C_2)j-((0)+C_3)k$$
$$C_1+C_2-C_3=8$$
This is as far as I've gotten, as I'm not sure how to get to the next step.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since the particle moves in a straight line, $v(t)$ must have the same direction vector as $a(t)$, which is $P_1-P_0$. Since you're given $|v(0)|=8$, can you figure out what $v(0)$ is and use that to compute $C_1$, $C_2$, and $C_3$?

Edit: The velocity vector is $s(t)\langle 1, 2, -1\rangle$, where $s(t)$ is the speed, since it is in the same direction as the acceleration vector. Then 
$$|v(0)| = s(0)\sqrt{6} = 8,$$
so that $s(0) = \frac{4}{3}\sqrt{6}$. This means that
$$v(0) = \frac{4}{3}\sqrt{6}\langle 1, 2, -1\rangle.$$
Does that help?

Comment: I've updated my question to show my attempt of trying to figure out v(0) but the answer could be any combination of things from the way I've tried to do it

Comment: I don't even know how that would be useful